# find and click on element by contain text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click an element by contains text

Here is my code

```
String bidname=  dataTable.getCommonData(CommonDataColumn.BidName);
System.out.println(bidname);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),bidname]")).click();
```

Actually I need to check from my excel sheet and then check the webpage if that text is present or not.

For example in my excel sheet my bid name are there, now I need to find if it is present on webpage and click on it.

Earlier I was hard coding it. But now I need to implement like above said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bidname` is a variable in your Java code. You need to append the value of `bidname` to the XPath string. Try:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'" + bidname + "')]")).click();
```

Comment: hi , the earlier code is like this.. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'117')]")).click();it is working. there is only one open braces not two . And i tried both .its not working

Comment: i tired this driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'"+bidname+"']")).click(); but its still not working

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),('" + bidname + "'))]")).click(); this is working.thanks i got the idea from you

Comment: @rishavkumar - You forgot to close the parenthesis for the `contains` function. I don't think you need to surround `bidname` value in parenthesis. I've edited the answer. Give my solution a try.